# display php forum topics list in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have android app. with a php forum. for the time being I have a single user table to store the user details 
but I did so coz I need to allow users to post and comments from the android interface to the forum.
I need to bring the list of topics from my forum and when user choose one of them it displays the content and he can click comment button to go to comment layout to write and send his/comments to the forum.

now I have made this php code to list the topics

```
<?php
//This page let display the list of topics of a category
  function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
}
 if(isset($_GET['parent']))
{
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
}
   $dn = mysql_query('select t.title,  u.username as author,  from topics as t left join topics left join user as u  where t.parent="'.$id.'" and t.id2=1 group by t.id order by t.timestamp2 desc');
if(mysql_num_rows($dn)>0)
  {
        $dn = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id = $parent");
        // return user details
        $posts = array();
          if(mysql_num_rows($dn)) {
            while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($dn)) {
              $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
            }
  }
    } else {
       // return false;
    }
?>
```

but I'm sure is correct or not also in my Android side should I create an array to hold this values to display..
I need to know if my concept is correct otherwise I'll be wasting my time...

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `I'm sure is correct or not`? Run it and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to print your information in a format you can parse from Android. I suggest JSON as it's simple and the preferred way to do it.

So, to summarize:

- Print your forum's information in JSON
- Perform an HTTP request from Android and get the response body
- Parse it with a JSON Library
- Optional but recommended: Transform it into a object to represent each element (each forum)